# Move documents from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, migration, export, import, explorer-view

I have an old sharepoint site containing around 50 document libraries with subfolders and files. No these document libraries should be moved to a new SharePoint 2010 site.

I've tried this using the copy and paste within the explorer viewer of both sites. But this does not work perfectly. Some subfolders are not copied for some reason. Also, if I paste the folders in the root of the SharePoint 2010 site, the document library does not show up when I browse to SharePoint site with "view all content".

I also tried opening the SharePoint 2010 site in SharePoint Designer 2010 but this is not supported. I've used the import method in SharePoint Designer to copy the files and folders to my local drive. But I did not succeed in moving these folders to the SharePoint 2010 site.

What is the supported method to move these documents within their document libraries to SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably content type issues when trying to copy from only library to another.  The supported way would be to upgrade the 2007 environment to 2010 then move the information over.  That's unrealistic for that few files.

I would recreate the folder structure in the 2010 environment manually, then copy the files via Open with Windows Explorer.

Comment: Ok, then i have some work to do. I'm lucky that there are not so many dirs :) Thanks for making this clear.

Comment: one more thing, is it normal that i get only 500bytes/sec when copy and paste to my local machine?

Comment: No that's not normal.  Check the Internet Explorer options to make sure the Automatically detect intranet is enabled in the Intranet Zone options on the Security tab, http://blindhole.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/slow-sharepoint-moss-2007-windows-explorer-view-using-windows-7-and-internet-explorer-8-ie8/

Comment: It's not an intranet here. I'm connecting to an internet site..

Comment: @Thomas Dekiere: After you copy the files to a folder on local machine, you can copy them to SharePoint 2010 library from there without any problem

Answer (score 1):

As Eric stated, you could simply "Open with Windows Explorer" on both environments and drag between the two. That said, if you care about last modified date/person or historical versions, this will remove them and start over since this essentially creates new entries in the 2010 environment.

If you need to preserve versions, you can look at one of the migration tools on the market (AvePoint has a great toolset), or you can do a database attach/upgrade of the 2007 content database into the 2010 environment. Obviously the third party tool option would have a cost associated with it, but the database attach method wouldn't.